# Intent.getData.getPath() returns a null value

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to get a file path from a capture image I take using the camera intent. Taking the pic and returning it works fine, but when I try to get the path from it in the OnActivityResult method by getting data from intent and getting its path, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.package.app/com.package.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List android.net.Uri.getPathSegments()' on a null object reference
```

As I said, the picture taking works, even managed to submit it to a mailing app as an attachment, no problems there, but getting its path is an issue. Here's the code of my OnActivityResult method (I've put a setText() on the TextView just to see what the getPath() result looks like):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        if(requestCode == 1){

            imageUri = data.getData();


        }
    }
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {


        imageUri = data.getData();
        path = imageUri.getPath();
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvField);
        tv.setText(path);


    }
}
```

Without the last 3 lines, it works flawlessly. Error points to the line:

```
path = imageUri.getPath();
```

Thanks for taking an interest in my problems in advance.

Here's the intent for Camera request

```
ibCam= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibCam);

        ibCam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

            }
        });
```

Comment: The results depends on the Intent which you are creating to start activity for result. You should include the code snippet where you are starting activity

Comment: Added up there...

Comment: `Taking the pic and returning it works fine`. You return a picture? To whom?

Comment: `imageUri = data.getData();`. We cannot see the type of `imageUri` but it should be Bitmap. As `data.getData()` delives a Bitmap. And bitmaps have no path.

Comment: I return the pic through the intent via OnActivtyResult in the URI object that later gets passed on in the Intent for the mailing app with putExtra method using the EXTRA_STREAM field.

If bitmap has no path, how should I go about getting the path from the taken picture?

Comment: You should google a bit for ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE.  Then you will discover that you have to supply a path on the intent where the picture then will be saved. You are victim #12345 which stumbles over the unexpected implementation of mentioned action. I hope the developers are fired meanwhile.

Comment: So basically I should just save the image retrieved from the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and later get its path?

Comment: No. That bitmap is only a thumbnail. Read my comment again. But better google for examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
imageUri = data.getData();
```

`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not return a `Uri`.

Given your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`, use `Bitmap photo=data.getParcelableExtra("data")` to retrieve the thumbnail-sized photo that you requested.

Comment: I have no problem retrieving the image using the `Uri`, I just need the path of the photo. Can I retrieve the bitmap and get its path?

Ultimately I want to submit this path as an attachment to an app using `javax.mail.Authenticator`

Comment: @MilesWeirdo: "I have no problem retrieving the image using the Uri" -- *a few* camera apps will put a `Uri` in the response. Most will not, because that is not [how `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is documented to work](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE). If you want a path, [use `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` request to tell the camera app where to place the photo](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath).